# Magento Login model email id with retrieve gender value from collection

Tags: magento-1.5

I am new to magento. How to load customer collection to retrieve gender value by passing login email id?

Thanks.

Praksah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik, Magento does not have explicit email id's for customers, only email addresses.

To retrieve the gender for a given email address you could use:

```
$oCustomer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->setWebsiteId(1)
    ->loadByEmail('example@example.com');

var_dump($oCustomer->getGender());
```

The `setWebsiteId(1)` part is only neccessary when running with website scope.